# Time and Memory Complexity of Removing All List Elements From Start

Tags: c#, data-structures, time-complexity

I searched for 2 days to find the answer but could'nt find it anywhere. The question is removing all elements from the start of a one million capacitied list. What would be the time complexity in **C#**. I am confused between **O(n) and O(n^n)**. If we formulize it, removing an element from start is **O(n)** so if we keep it going like that it will be **O(n)O(n-1)O(n-2)...O(n-n)** but I could'nt be sure about it. Here is the code.

```
List<int> million = new List<int>(1000000);
while (million.Count > 0)
{
     million.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Sum of integers from 0 to k is quadratic: https://letstalkscience.ca/educational-resources/backgrounders/gauss-summation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all that would give n!, not n^n.

But that is irrelevant, because that should be sum, not product. If removing one element takes n steps, then applying this n times gives

```
n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1
```

steps, since each step is shorter than previous one by 1. The sum is [well known to be equal to n(n+1)/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), i.e. O(n^2).

Comment: I suspect the real performance won't be so neat. [RemoveAt](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L970) copies the rest of the data to the left, which is subject to optimizations, memory locality, any SIMD tricks the JIT runtime and compiler may decide to use.

Comment: It doesn't matter what optimizations it employs, it still has to traverse all but one elements. The time complexity is linear.

Comment: @Blindy you are right about all the mentioned optimizations. However, that is not necessarily true in general. I think it is possible for the compiler to replace this loop with simple O(n) removal, no? In fact with ints (and potentially other structs that do not reference managed objects) it should even be able to do this in O(1).

Comment: Theoretically it could, but it won't. This is the kind of thing a really strong C++ compiler could do, but the .Net JIT is made to compile fast, not to generate the best code.

Answer (score 1):

That's `O(n^2)`. The outer loop runs `n` times (`O(n)`), and removing items is `O(n)`, so overall it's `O(n) * O(n) ⊂ O(n^2)`.